# img resizing automatically keeping the line

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm having trouble with two img in same div. I need to make them stay on one line, and resize image on the left when the right touch her.

Fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/SZd3r/1/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <header class="container relative">
        <a class="left logo"><img src="#" width="248" height="52" alt="" /></a>
        <a class="right" href="#"><img src="" /><img src="#" width="32" height="32" alt="" /></a>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </header>
</div>

.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 220px;
    max-width: 1024px;
}
.relative {
    position: relative;
}
.left {
    float: left;
}
.right {
    float: right;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Resize the navigator to view this.

**What I want to achieve, is to reduce the image, decreasing the width smoothly, just enough to reach minimum width. Automatic.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To flexibilize your layout, a plausible solution is the Flexbox.

See: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

The compatibility list can be found at: http://caniuse.com/flexbox

To make a flexible box uses a few lines of code, for example:

```
.flex {
    display: flex;
}
```

Add this class to your box. A lot of settings can be found in the reported material.

For maximum compatibility, use the vendors prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

use css3 media queries https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

So Just Add this:

```
@media (max-width: 300px) {
  .left {
    width: 80%;
  }

}
```

Comment: This solves in part, and I've done it, but it's a kludge. The image will not be resized smoothly. It's a sharp and full manual reduction. What I want to achieve, is to reduce the image, decreasing the width smoothly, just enough to to reach minimum width. Automatic.

Comment: Sorry so I don't have other solutions I usully use a css framework that facilate the work specially for the responsive exp Bootstrap and their grid system http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Thank you for trying friend. I know the bootstrap, but I'm not wanting to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a fluid width to the image's container:

```
a.left {
  width: 85%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SZd3r/3/

Comment: Not solve man. Look. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hvmxt    with 85% of width, the a element will occupy 80% of the space, and is not exactly what I want, see the second img will never touch her.